# How to download a single file using Session.GetFiles in WinSCP C#

Tags: c#, .net, winscp, winscp-net

So, basically I am trying to download only one file from the entire folder on my server.

Folder "domain" contains those files right now:

> File1.txt
>   File2.txt
>   File3.txt

So, as I can see in WinSCP docs if I want to download only one file I still should use `Session.GetFiles()` ([method docs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles)) with full path to file. Okay, but I can't understand what's my problem, because it's not working.

```
session.GetFiles("/domains/domain/File1.txt", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

However if I change the remote path to whole directory, not a single file I need it works great, but I don't need all three .txt files.

```
session.GetFiles("/domains/domain/", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation for the [`localPath` argument of `Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles#localpath) says, the argument is:

> Full path to download the file to.

So it should be:

```
var localPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "File1.txt");
session.GetFiles("/domains/domain/File1.txt", localPath);
```

---

Alternatively, you can simplify the code by using [`Session.GetFileToDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiletodirectory), which does what you have expected from `Session.GetFiles`:

```
session.GetFileToDirectory(
    "/domains/domain/File1.txt", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

---

See also https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_vs_gui#inputs